# Beedle Zelda BOTW voice actor

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Just playing through BOTW and find Beedle's voice funny. Anyone know who the voice actor is. (I am playing English version)

Comment: I'm not certain that the voice actors are credited specifically except for the characters that appear in fully voiced cutscenes.

Comment: yeah i thought as much. i see on IMDB many voice actors are credited without a character name (perhaps they did several each?) , was just wondering maybe someone actually knew him, or worked on the game, might be able to put a name to the voice so i could look him up and see his face haha :D no worries guys ;]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a list of credited major voice actors.
https://www.behindthevoiceactors.com/video-games/The-Legend-of-Zelda-Breath-of-the-Wild/
IMDB has a full list of voice actors, however, this list doesn't tell you voices for random grunts and sounds (like "Wow!" "Oh ho!" "Ahhh!"), which is most of what the minor characters do.  Beedle is basically in this category.
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3253986/fullcredits

In other words, you are required to recognize his voice in order to pick that name out of any other voice actors.